# How to output lowercase strings in AwesomeWM rc.lua?

Tags: unix, lua, x11, pango, awesome-wm

I'm using AwesomeWM vicious datewidget. I'm trying to output the date and time in wibox, in my rc.lua, with this format `Feb 17, 12:10 AM` (%b %d, %l:%M:%p) but I want the `AM`(%p) to be lowercase.

I've tried: `vicious.register(datewidget, vicious.widgets.date, "<span font-family='terminus' color='#999999'>%b %d, %l:%M:</span> <span variant='smallcaps'%p</span>", 1)` but the variant attribute doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way to do this?

my full [rc.lua](http://pastebin.com/ThtNDBg6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string` library's `lower()` call.

```
os.date( "%b, %I:%M " )..string.lower( os.date("%p") )
```

---

### Edit

Though it is not mentioned in [Lua PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html); the [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) also has `%P` to format as lowercase `am` or `pm`.

The string can be:

```
os.date( "%b, %I:%M %P" )
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/p7fL49m3) example.