# AwesomeWM time not updating?

Tags: linux, unix, lua, x11, awesome-wm

I'm using AwesomeWM, and I'm trying to display the time in my wibox using this code

```
vicious.register(datewidget, vicious.widgets.date, os.date("%b ")..(os.date("%d")+0).. ', ' ..(os.date("%I")+0)..os.date(":%M")..string.lower( os.date(" %p ")), 1)
```

The time is correct when I open *AwesomeWM*, but it doesn't update. For whatever reason `, 1)` doesn't work.

heres my full [rc.lua](http://pastebin.com/Heg8YyPB)

Comment: Instead of so many concatenations; a simple: `os.date("%b %d, %I:%M ")..string.lower( os.date("%p ")` would work as you're just adding 0 to those values.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with what the register function expects. It expects a format string with which it can calculate date itself. Here you're passing a literal string instead of formatting parameters.

From your older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919094/1190388), I found a different method for the same. Now, your `vicious` need to be like:

```
vicious.register(datewidget, vicious.widgets.date, "<span font-family='terminus' color='#999999'>%b %d, %l:%M %P</span>", 1)
```

And it should work.

**P.S.** Thanks to [sa1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325211/sa1)

Comment: This updates but I'm not sure how to format it with the lowercase AM/PM.

Comment: @user10850 Did you use `%P`? Notice that there's **`P`** and not `p`.

Comment: `%P` is outputting `P`. `%p` is outputting `PM`